# Visual Studio 2008 - Solution Explorer Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a problem I can't seem to figure out. When I open my project all the files in Solution Explorer have all there own subfolders. For example instead of a folder called css with a few files in it, I have a few css folders each with 1 file in it. However, I open the project on my coworkers machine and it opens fine. Any ideas if there is a setting or something I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah especially when I have a bunch of css and image files and there is a ton of folders now. But it opens fine on my coworkers machine from the same solution on a network share.

Comment: Its a BlackBerry Webworks project so I need the thrid party extension to load.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using source control? Visual Studio 2008 has a few quirks...as a rule whenever something strange like this occurs it is time to close and re-open the solution.

If this does not help, I would rename my project folder to back up my files, then create a fresh copy from the known good project that works on your colleague's machine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Visual studio automatically writes user-specific files to the solution folder, this could be causing you grief. When you grab a fresh copy, remove any *.suo, *.cache or *.user files. Then I strongly suggest you check the source files into source control and each of you check out your own copy of the solution. Subversion and Git are both free, Team Foundation Server is fantastic if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is when I open the project off the network share the foldering gets all messed up. Easy fix is just to copy it to my local drive.